# save values as a string array instead of comma delimited string in a custom xtype CQ5

Tags: extjs, widget, adobe, aem

I have created a custom xtype for multiselect, but i am not able to understand what changes i need to perform to save the values as a string array instead of comma delimited string.

Currently it is storing the values as follows

**Property** industry
**Type**     String
**Value**    government,healthcare

Instead, i want to save the information as follows

**Property** industry
**Type**     String[]
**Value**    government,healthcare

Any suggestions, pointers highly appreciated.

```
CQ.Ext.form.Multiselect = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.Ext.form.Field,  {
store:null,
storeUrl:'',
displayField:'text',
valueField:'value',
allowBlank:true,
minLength:0,
blankText:CQ.Ext.form.TextField.prototype.blankText,
copy:false,
allowDup:false,
allowTrash:false,
legend:null,
focusClass:undefined,
delimiter:',',
view:null,
dragGroup:null,
dropGroup:null,
tbar:null,
appendOnly:false,
sortField:null,
sortDir:'ASC',
defaultAutoCreate : {tag: "div"},


initComponent: function(){
    CQ.Ext.form.Multiselect.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    this.addEvents({
        'dblclick' : true,
        'click' : true,
        'change' : true,
        'drop' : true
    });    
},
onRender: function(ct, position){
    var fs, cls, tpl;
    CQ.Ext.form.Multiselect.superclass.onRender.call(this, ct, position);

    cls = 'ux-mselect';

    fs = new CQ.Ext.form.FieldSet({
        renderTo:this.el,
        title:this.legend,
        height:this.height,
        width:this.width,
        style:"padding:1px;",
        tbar:this.tbar
    });
    if(!this.legend){
    //fs.el.down('.'+fs.headerCls).remove();
    fs.body.addClass(cls);
    }
    tpl = '<tpl for="."><div class="' + cls + '-item';
    if(CQ.Ext.isIE || CQ.Ext.isIE7 || CQ.Ext.isOpera )tpl+='" unselectable=on';
    else tpl+=' x-unselectable"';
    tpl+='>{' + this.displayField + '}</div></tpl>';


     this.store = new CQ.Ext.data.JsonStore({
            autoload:true,
            url: CQ.HTTP.externalize(this.storeUrl),
            fields:['value','text']

    });

     this.store.load();


    this.view = new CQ.Ext.ux.DDView({
        multiSelect: true, store: this.store, selectedClass: cls+"-selected", tpl:tpl,
        allowDup:this.allowDup, copy: this.copy, allowTrash: this.allowTrash,
        dragGroup: this.dragGroup, dropGroup: this.dropGroup, itemSelector:"."+cls+"-item",
        isFormField:false, applyTo:fs.body, appendOnly:this.appendOnly,
        sortField:this.sortField, sortDir:this.sortDir
    });

    fs.add(this.view);

    this.view.on('click', this.onViewClick, this);
    this.view.on('beforeClick', this.onViewBeforeClick, this);
    this.view.on('dblclick', this.onViewDblClick, this);
    this.view.on('drop', function(ddView, n, dd, e, data){
        return this.fireEvent("drop", ddView, n, dd, e, data);
    }, this);

    this.hiddenName = this.name;
    var hiddenTag={tag: "input", type: "hidden", value: "", name:this.name};
    if (this.isFormField) {
        this.hiddenField = this.el.createChild(hiddenTag);
    } else {
        this.hiddenField = CQ.Ext.get(document.body).createChild(hiddenTag);
    }
    fs.doLayout();
},

initValue:CQ.Ext.emptyFn,

onViewClick: function(vw, index, node, e) {
    var arrayIndex = this.preClickSelections.indexOf(index);
    if (arrayIndex  != -1)
    {
        this.preClickSelections.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
        this.view.clearSelections(true);
        this.view.select(this.preClickSelections);
    }
    this.fireEvent('change', this, this.getValue(), this.hiddenField.dom.value);
    this.hiddenField.dom.value = this.getValue();
    this.fireEvent('click', this, e);
    this.validate();       
},

onViewBeforeClick: function(vw, index, node, e) {
    this.preClickSelections = this.view.getSelectedIndexes();
    if (this.disabled) {return false;}
},

onViewDblClick : function(vw, index, node, e) {
    return this.fireEvent('dblclick', vw, index, node, e);
}, 

getValue: function(valueField){
    var returnArray = [];
    var selectionsArray = this.view.getSelectedIndexes();
    if (selectionsArray.length == 0) {return '';}
    for (var i=0; i<selectionsArray.length; i++) {
        returnArray.push(this.store.getAt(selectionsArray[i]).get(((valueField != null)? valueField : this.valueField)));
    }
    return returnArray;
},

setValue: function(values) {
    var index;
    var selections = [];
    this.view.clearSelections();
    this.hiddenField.dom.value = '';

    if (!values || (values == '')) { return; }

    if (!(values instanceof Array)) { values = values.split(this.delimiter); }
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        index = this.view.store.indexOf(this.view.store.query(this.valueField,
            new RegExp('^' + values[i] + '$', "i")).itemAt(0));
        selections.push(index);
    }
    this.view.select(selections);
    this.hiddenField.dom.value = values;
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
     this.listOfIndustries=values[i];
     alert(values[i]);
    }
    this.validate();
},   

getRawValue: function(valueField) {
    var tmp = this.getValue(valueField);

    if (!tmp) {

        tmp = [];
    }

    return tmp;
},

setRawValue: function(values){
    setValue(values);
},

validateValue : function(value){
    if (value.length < 1) { // if it has no value
         if (this.allowBlank) {
             this.clearInvalid();
             return true;
         } else {
             this.markInvalid(this.blankText);
             return false;
         }
    }
    if (value.length < this.minLength) {
        this.markInvalid(String.format(this.minLengthText, this.minLength));
        return false;
    }
    if (value.length > this.maxLength) {
        this.markInvalid(String.format(this.maxLengthText, this.maxLength));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
});

CQ.Ext.reg("industriesmultiselect", CQ.Ext.form.Multiselect);
```

Envionment CQ 5.5

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
Instead of using the one hidden field to store your values, you need to use multiple underlying `input` elements, each having the same `name` property for the Sling Post Servlet to interpret the output as a multi-valued property. See the multifield widget's `setValue` and `addItem` methods at `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/MultiField.js` for an example of dynamically adding new fields.

**Longer explanation:**
It looks like your `getValue` does what you expect, but the problem is that that method isn't getting called to provide the value that gets submitted. If you're using this widget in a standard dialog, the parent form panel submits the values that are specified in the input elements beneath it in the DOM hierarchy.

In other words, you need to apply your multiple values to DOM elements.

The `CQ.Ext.form.Field` that you're extending only defines one underlying input element, which you're trying to set with your values array in `setValue`:

```
this.hiddenField.dom.value = values;
```

and in `onViewClick`

```
this.hiddenField.dom.value = this.getValue();
```

Since `hiddenField` is an input tag of type 'hidden', it holds a string value and when you try to set it this way, you're actually storing the result of calling `toString()` on your values array. This is why you end up with one string of comma separated values getting submitted.

You'll need to maintain a whole set of hidden fields if you want this widget to work with the standard form submission infrastructure. Alternatively, you could implement your own submit event listener wherever appropriate and use Ext or jQuery to POST an AJAX request with your array (directly from `getValue()`) as one of the parameters.